# Could not find iPhone X simulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am unable to run react-native project on iPhone.

I am using

```
Xcode version: 11.0
react-native: 0.61.1
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

whenever I run `react-native run-ios` it always throw and error saying

> info Found Xcode project "AwesomeProject.xcodeproj" error Could not
>   find "iPhone X" simulator. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more
>   details.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Open Xcode -> Preferences -> Components -> (Download any simulator) (I have downloaded ios 12.2) and hit command react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the new react native cli tools `npm i @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios --save` or use [this solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23282#issuecomment-460623632), the same applies for cli-platform-android, if the package is already installed for you, [this solution may work for you](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/418#issuecomment-530172299)